# Cannot Change the Fiori Page

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I have a simple Fiori application. I want to delete some texts in it.

[image: Texts to delete]

I have little knowledge about UI5, and I found that the text is in the file "Detail.View.xml".

```
<ObjectHeader
  id="objectHeader"
  title="{
    path: 'Zperiod',
    formatter: '.sText1'
  }"
  number="{Pernr}">
    <statuses>
      <ObjectStatus
        text="带薪年假剩余{Zsfnj}天"
        state="Error" />
      <ObjectStatus
        text="带薪病假剩余{Zsybj}天"
        state="Success"
        visible="{
          path: 'Znote1',
          formatter: '.statusText'
        }"/>
      <ObjectStatus
        text="调休假剩余{Znumc1}天"
        state="Warning" />
    </statuses>
  <attributes>
    <ObjectAttribute text="{Name2}" />
    <ObjectAttribute text="{Orgtx}" />
    <ObjectAttribute text="{Plstx}" />
  </attributes>
</ObjectHeader>
```

I replaced the texts with `text=""` in *SE80*, saved, and activated it. But when I open the application again, the texts are still there.

(My colleague told me we have an independent AS for Fiori application, and we can change object in PRD. So no transport needed.)

I cannot understand the appearance. Could someone tell me why my modification has no effect?

Comment: if not already done, please delete the cache of the browser or reload the application in incognito or privacy modus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an cache issue.
After clearing cache by transaction *SMICM*, it works fine.

Thanks for all your comments, especially @boghyon, your edit give me a lot of help.